# ImageView just disappears and I can't get it to show

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to show a list of items and be able to put a marker on certain items. However, no matter what the marker will not show but the rest of the view does, yet in Eclipse the layout editor shows it.

The layout is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp" >

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="#322"
    android:id="@+id/image" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="Hello world"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
    android:id="@+id/title" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in my ListAdapter I try to make it show like so:

```
    iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    Log.d("trakt", ti.glyph + "");
    if(ti.glyph == 0){
        iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else{
        Log.d("trakt", "showing glyph");
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // iv.setImageResource(ti.glyph); - this is disabled for now
    }
```

The logging shows the correct number and "showing glyph", except it doesn't appear on-screen

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the marker behind the text view, try moving it to the front using iv.bringToFront()